# HSTS header with Tomcat 9 for 400 Errors

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, tomcat9, hsts, strict-transport-security

Using a Tomcat v9.0.30, I was able to successfully configure HSTS headers for all responses (when served over HTTPS) for my Spring-based app using the built-in Tomcat filter *HttpHeaderSecurityFilter*
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html

However, I have noticed that the headers were not added for a particular response with a 400 HttpStatus. Below are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The issue seems to be specific to 400 Errors and particularly when non-compliant chars to rfc 7230 and rfc 3986 are used: "["

I know that these chars are now rejected by default by Tomcat v9.x.x for security reasons and that it can be allowed using the *relaxedPathChars* and *relaxedQueryChars* properties, but what about the 400 error response ?

Why is the HSTS header not added in that case and is there a workaround (Add the headers for the 400 response) ? Should it be reported as a bug on Tomcat, if the *HttpHeaderSecurityFilter* is supposed to be applied for all responses ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `relaxedPathChars='[]'` to the `Connector` element in `server.xml` fixed this for me on Tomcat 9.0.65.

I ended up using the following configuration to allow even more characters (to satisfy a security scan):
`server.xml` -> `Connector` ->

```
relaxedPathChars='[]|' relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;'
```

and setting the following start option (to allow `[encoded]` backslashes without the HSTS header breaking):

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```